# How can I draw a horizontal line and center it?

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-7, line

Here's what I have so far.

When the phone is vertical:

[image]

When the phone is horizontal:
[image]

Here's my XAML markup:

```
<StackPanel Margin="19 0 19 5">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                Stretch="Uniform"
                Margin="0 10 0 10"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="14 0 0 0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                        FontSize="30" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" 
                        FontSize="22"
                        Foreground="#E0A655"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Synopsis}"
                        FontSize="22"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>                                                        
    </Grid>
    <Line StrokeThickness="4" Stroke="#434343" X1="0" X2="350"
        Y1="13" Y2="13" />
</StackPanel>
```

I'd like a line that is the same width as it currently is, but centered. But also when the phone is horizontal, the line should be a bit bigger to address the wider space available to it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have that kind of sizing by using margin to size your content instead of positions.

If that's not possible with a Line (I haven't really checked), you might try to use a 1 pixel high (or 4 rather) Rectangle.

EDIT: with a code snippet:

```
<Line HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50, 10, 50, 10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
```

Comment: Wow, worked better than expected. :) I'll mark this as solved once the timer hits zero.

Comment: @Sergio: I guessed so, well... I've added a small snippet to better show what I mean.

Comment: Since a Google produces this for Windows Phone 8 as well, the same is possible however borrowing from ColinE's answer below you also need to specify `X2="1"` so that the line has _some_ length and `Stretch="Fill"` so that your short line fills the area defined by your margins.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Stretch` to make your `Line` occupy the full width of the container. You can also use left / right margins to add a little space at each side:

```
<Line X1="0" X2="1" Stretch="Fill" Margin="20,0,20,0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit surprising at the first view: Lines (as well as other shapes - Rectangle, Ellipse...) are FrameworkElements. You can handle them in the same way as for example a TextBlock, i.e. set dimensions, alignments, margin, opacity, transform etc. You can even animate/bind shape-defining properties (such as Line.X1) as they are all DependencyProperties.